# How to read this crossed association in an UML class-diagram?

Tags: java, uml, associations, class-diagram

Here the class diagram:

```
 ---------                   ---------
|          |*             1 |         |
| class    |-X------------->|  class  |
|CourseExec|    +courseExec |  Course |
 ---------                   ---------
```

I know a `CourseExec` has exactly 1 `Course` and a `Course` can have many `CourseExec`, but what does the cross (`X`) means here?

In other words, how does the X in the relation impact the way I read it?

Comment: Actually this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508099/uml-non-navigable-relationships-use-or-example

Comment: Nice adittion of a java apllication in the comments of the answer from Cristophe!

Comment: He's amongst the best explanators here on SO (at least in the UML area). He must be some sort of professor :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UML Non-Navigable Relationships - Use or Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508099/uml-non-navigable-relationships-use-or-example)

Answer (score 4):

This is an indication of a non navigable association:

`CourseExec` is navigable (`—->`) to `Course` means that there is a guarantee that an instance of `CourseExec` can easily find its related ‘Course` instances at runtime.

`Course` is not navigable (`-X—`) to `CourseExec` means that there is no guarantee of easy finding the related instance, and that on contrary it could be very difficult, slow or even impossible.

The notation is not very common because usually people tend to leave the opposite navigation unspecified.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So, to see if I got that, Course being not navigable to CourseExec, translating to java would mean that there should be no instance of a Collection of CourseExecs on the Course class? Or would that still happen and I'm getting it wrong when apllying it to java

Comment: @fckincocas yes, exactly.

Comment: Awesome, cheers